# How to resize d3 map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, gis

I have this map in d3 consisting of a chart and map:

I define a few global variables:

```
var chartWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.425,
chartHeight = 473,
leftPadding = 35,
rightPadding = 2,
topBottomPadding = 5,
innerWidth = chartWidth - leftPadding - rightPadding,
innerHeight = chartHeight - topBottomPadding * 2,
translate = "translate(" + leftPadding + "," + topBottomPadding + ")";
```

Here's the map:

```
//set up the map
function setMap(){
    var width = window.innerWidth * 0.55, //dimensions
        height = 580; //dimensions

//create new svg container for the map
var map = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "map")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

And a linked chart:

```
 function setChart(csvData, colorScale, attribute){

var expressed = attribute
    //create a second svg element to hold the bar chart
    var chart = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", chartWidth)
        .attr("height", chartHeight)
        //assign class
        .attr("class", "chart");

    //create a rectangle for chart background fill
    var chartBackground = chart.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "chartBackground")
        .attr("width", innerWidth)
        .attr("height", innerHeight)
        .attr("transform", translate);
    
}
```

I'm trying to make the map (the map itself and the associated chart, both are appended to 'map' canvas) responsive, so it will resize when window is resized.  I've inserted the following code in the setMap function with no luck, hoping to re-class the 'map' on re-size:

```
   d3.select("map")
   .append("div")
   .classed("svg-container", true) //container class to make it responsive
   .append("svg")
   //responsive SVG needs these 2 attributes and no width and height attr
   .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
   .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
   //class to make it responsive
   .classed("svg-content-responsive", true);
```

What can I try to achieve this?

Comment: I see you've set the `viewBox` attribute for the SVG. If your SVG has also a width &/or a height attributes please remove them.

Comment: Thanks - like declare them as value-less variables?  Could you explain?  Part of the problem i'm noticing is that the svg-content-responsive div has a ton of extra whitespace, which overlaps with other divs.  Setting the margins and padding to 0 doesnt seem to work.